# mongodb: remove entire child element with multiple conditions

Tags: mongodb

Today is my first day using MongoDB

My collection format:

```
{ "_id" : "ObjectId" :"4f2ff1d00cf2f86576f91a91"),
"fishStuff" : [
{
    "name" : "GreatWhite",
    "fID" : 50
},
{
    "name" : "Hammerhead",
    "fID" : 51
},
{
    "name" : "White",
    "fID" : 60
}
], "fishSpecies" : "Oceanic"
```

...

I want to write a query in the shell (straight up mongo) that will delete the third child (name: White) because the 1st child exists in this group of "fishStuff".

I believe the "where" clause should be :

{fishSpecies:"Oceanic","fishStuff.fID":50, "fishStuff.fID:60}

So how do I delete the entire "60" child element?  I want to delete every "60" element in the collection when "50" is also in the same "fishStuff" group/array. Also, the reason I've included fishSpecies in the "where" clause is because there is more than one fishSpecies possibility.

UPDATE:

I have tried the suggestions left by the two commenters below and am still getting 7 instances (after running the count below) of child object sets that contain both fID 50 and 60:

```
> db.fish.update({fishSpecies:"oceanic","fishStuff.fID":50}, {$pull : {"fishStuff" : { fID : 60}}},false, true)
> db.fish.find({"fishSpecies":"oceanic","fishStuff.fID":50, "fishStuff.fID":60}).count()
7
```

The multi: true flag does not work (or I am not implementing it correctly) as zero records are updated.

Comment: Am i right in thinking you want all `fishStuff.fId` == 50 || 60 removed from the array? have you tried `db.mycollection.update({fishSpecies:"oceanic"}, {$pull : {"fishStuff" : { fId : 50}}}, false, true)` to make sure the 50 works. You could use $in or run update for each element you want to `$pull`

Comment: No, and I am sorry for my poorly written question.  My goal: If a fishStuff group (collection of child elements-not sure of proper terminology) contains both 50 AND 60, I want to remove 60.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to remove based on it's ordinal position (index) then you can't directly.

You can use a technique to $unset the item in the array then $pull it.

```
db.mycollection.update({}, {$unset : {"fishStuff.50" : 1 }})
db.mycollection.update({}, {$pull : {"fishStuff" : null}})
```

It's worth noting though, this doesn't take into account the fId, and solely relies on the document's position in the array.

To pull the item matching your fId you need to:

```
 db.mycollection.update({}, {$pull : {"fishStuff" : { fId : 50}}})
```

EDIT:

If you're wanting to remove the elements where fId == 50 from the array where the document's array contains fId == 50 and fId == 60 you should be able to:

```
db.mycollection.update({
    "fishSpecies":"oceanic",
    "fishStuff.fId": { $all : [50,60]}}, 
    // update
    {$pull : {"fishStuff" : { fId : 50}}
})
```

Comment: I'm trying to remove it based on the fID.  If fID 50 and fID60 are in the same array, I want to remove fID 60.  So the position in the index is not relevant to my goal.  They could appear in any order.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you're looking for...

Checks mycollection for documents that match fishSpecies with Oceanic AND fID = 50- removes fID = 60 element if so.  multi:true scans the entire collection.

```
db.mycollection.update({'fishSpecies': 'Oceanic','fishStuff':{fID:50}}, {$pull:{'fishStuff': {fID: 60}}}, {multi:true})
```